# Displaying PDF file from Azure Blob Storage container in new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-blob-storage

Similar question has definitely been asked before and I tried the solutions provided there, still not able to figure it out.

I am fetching a PDF file stored in Azure blob storage container. Since azure gives me a direct link to access the file, I copied that link and pasted in my browser window and the file gets downloaded.

As per my requirement I need to display that file in browsers new tab, so I tried with following code inside one of the methods:

```
const config = {
 responseType: "blob"
};
try {
  const res = await axios.get(apiUrl, config);

  const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });

  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
  } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
  }
```

by doing this when this method is called, the new tab get opened and closed immediately. How can I keep the new tab opened until user closes it themselves??

[image: Issue can be seen in attached GIF here]

Comment: why dont u show pdf over api? u could take pdf with api and return file to your fronend

Comment: Umm... am new to azure, can you please let me know from where can I get this API?? Is this API being provided by azure?? or do I need to write one?

Comment: What's your pdf blob `CONTENT-TYPE` stored in azure?

Comment: CONTENT-TYPE is "application/octet-stream"

Comment: You could try to upload your pdf file with the `application/pdf` content-type. My pdf file could open with browser with this type.

Comment: @BijaySingh Could you please tell me how you get blob data?

Comment: @GeorgeChen am using blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(), how to set CONTENT-TYPE to 'application/pdf' in this??

Comment: @JimXu azure stroage blob container gives me an URL to access the files stored over there, using that am getting the blob

Comment: Check the [createBlockBlobFromStream](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-storage-legacy/latest/BlobService.html#createBlockBlobFromStream) method there is a option to set the content type. Or you could refer to this sample https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/4bffbc9920b9252b373cd0f6ff1ecde988b17d30/test/services/blob/blobservice-uploaddownload-tests.js#L1660

Comment: @GeorgeChen thanks for sharing the link, I was able to update the CONTENT-TYPE to application/pdf, still the issue persist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @GeorgeChen above, I changed the CONTENT-TYPE to application/pdf and then I cleared my browser's cache and restarted my application, and my issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this issue is to set the `content-type` to `application/pdf` *during the initial upload*. It is possible to set the content-type of a PDF file (or any file) *after* uploading but it is optimal to pass the correct headers the first time.

**How to set the content-type for an Azure blob storage upload with the Node.js SDK:**

```
const exampleBuffer = data; // type: Buffer
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
    yourAzureStorageConnectionStringHere,
);
const containerName = `example-container`; // container name here
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    containerName,
);
const containerExists = await containerClient.exists(); // check if container exists
if (!containerExists) await containerClient.create(); // create container if it doesn't exist
const blobName = 'example name'; // blob file name here
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'application/pdf' }}; // this is where you set all blob options, including the header and content-type
await blockBlobClient.upload(bufferData, bufferData.length, blobOptions); // upload the blob with the data and blob options
```